# Convert Comma Separated column value to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, delimiter

I have a table  **Sample** with data stored like below

| Id | String |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc,def,ghi |
| 2 | jkl,mno,pqr |

I need the output like..

| Id | processedrows |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 1 | def |
| 1 | ghi |
| 2 | jkl |
| 2 | mno |
| 2 | pqr |

How can I do the same with a select query in SQL Server?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: tell me more about your problem! what is your table? or it's schema

Comment: First of all, you're using a bad data model. Comma-delimited strings should prettymuch never be in databases. Period.

Comment: While people are willing to help, please search the archives first. Splitting a CSV string is a very common question. Though I agree with Jack Maney, if at all possible - you should change your data model. Storing CSV strings is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: Never is long time.  I completely agree that storing comma-separated lists is a recipe for trouble, but denormalization has its place.  That said, storing lists in a single column and then access the elements of the list individually with SQL is bound to be awkward.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574

Comment: Agreed, few things are 100% absolute. Maybe another way to put it is "do not use that structure without a good reason and understanding of the drawbacks and limitations." (If you have to ask what those are - you probably do not have a compelling reason to use it ;)

Comment: Why are so many comments telling this guy that his data model is "wrong"?  In my experience, you don't always get to dictate the data model, or maybe this model works just fine for him.  Either he's dealing with someone else's mistake or he's got the data model he wants.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT A.[id],  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT [id],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([string], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  TableA) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

refer here

http://www.sqljason.com/2010/05/converting-single-comma-separated-row.html

Comment: Nice answer, but for special characters or multilingual need to change Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') to Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)')

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Certs
FROM
(
SELECT EmployeeID,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Certs,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   @t
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question, but it doesn't seem to; the question doesn't have a field called `EmployeeID`, and turning the string values into XML seems like massive overkill to me...

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

New way of doing this:

```
    SELECT
         a.Id,
         b.value
    FROM
         Sample a 
         cross apply string_split(a.string,',') b
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the below script:-

```
declare @str varchar(max)

SELECT @str = isnull(@str +',', '') + a.Value
FROM (SELECT Value Entityvalue from Table) a

select @str
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. You will get your output.

```
SELECT id,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'-','.'),1) 'Values' 
FROM  
(
     SELECT algorithms,
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(string, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
     FROM   <TableName> 
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```