# how to get the count of GROUP

Tags: sql

```
ID  GROUP       NAME
1   1,2,      Supreeth
2   1,2,5,      Aishu
3   3,         Arvi
4   4,5,       Gani
5   4,3,2,      Jyo
6   3,2,1,      Upi
7   2,3,4,1,5,  Savi
```

I have table like this, I'm trying to get the count of group

```
    DECODE    Count
1   A         4
2   B         5
3   C         4
4   D         3
5   E         3
```

I wanted to decode the values of group to the DECODE values like 1 to A , 2 to B ,3 to C , 4 to D, 5 to E..

Im trying like this but get errors

```
select  count(*) from s_c where age like '%1%' and '%2%' and '%3%';
```

Comment: `like '%1%' and '%2%' and '%3%'` isn't valid SQL.

Comment: @Carl Saldanha : thank you for editing and correcting me

Comment: @Mike Christensen : please tell me how can i go about in achieving the req output

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  When you ask questions about databases, please give the names of your tables; it makes the answers more uniform and comparable.  This table schema illustrates why you should normalize your data!  When you store lists of values in a single column, you run into difficulties when you need to analyze it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : this is all ready an existing database

Comment: I know this isn't what you're looking for... But seriously consider dropping that group column. That is most definitely a non-relational way of doing things. Another table with schema YOURFIRSTTABLEID, GROUP, and then just had multiple rows per name, would make queries like this far easier (and more efficient later, since string parsing isn't exactly sql's greatest strength).

Comment: You probably mean something like this, but it will only help if your group names are all 1 character, and again please see other comments for why the database design is very poor: select count(*) from s_c where group like '%1%' or group like '%2%' or group like '%3%'

Comment: OK; it is a pre-existing database with a sloppy schema design.  This probably isn't the worst problem in the database, but it does make analysis hard -- which is why I'm claiming it is badly designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution might not be good, or flexible as it depends on hard coded values but it achieves the desired output as described in the question:

```
SELECT 1 AS [Num], 'A' AS Decode, COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM my_table WHERE [Group] LIKE '%1%'
UNION
SELECT 2 AS [Num], 'B' AS Decode, COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM my_table WHERE [Group] LIKE '%2%'
UNION
SELECT 3 AS [Num], 'C' AS Decode, COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM my_table WHERE [Group] LIKE '%3%'
UNION
SELECT 4 AS [Num], 'D' AS Decode, COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM my_table WHERE [Group] LIKE '%4%'
UNION
SELECT 5 AS [Num], 'E' AS Decode, COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM my_table WHERE [Group] LIKE '%5%'
```

Comment: In standard SQL, you'd need a GROUP BY clause in each of the SELECT statements within the UNION.  Also, picking nits, the output in the question as a numeric column with values 1-5 for decode values A-E.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wasn't aware of the need for GROUP BY in union. As for the output I thought the numbers were just meant to be for  explaining the desired output as there wasn't any header for the numbers. I guess I misunderstood that part.

Comment: The numbers as row identifiers is a 'not impossible' interpretation of the output -- and the lacking of heading for that column gave me pause for thought.  It's a problem with a slightly loosely written question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Btw, do you have a reference for `In standard SQL, you'd need a GROUP BY clause in each of the SELECT statements within the UNION.`. Very curious as this isn't how I was taught in my DB courses at uni.

Comment: There are various possibilities, including: (1) the standard has changed; (2) the university was wrong; (3) the DBMS you use doesn't need it even though the standard does.  Historically (SQL-99, SQL-92, SQL-89, SQL-86), the GROUP BY was necessary.  In more modern times (SQL-2003, SQL-2008, SQL-2011), things may have changed.

Answer (score 3):

One simple minded (not necessarily efficient) approach is to obtain the separate counts for each of the group values.  Note that the column name `Group` is using a reserved word, so you have to use an appropriate delimited identifier notation.  When you use the portable (SQL standard) double quotes, you have to get the case of the identifier correct; I've assumed lower case — YMMV.

```
SELECT 1 AS GroupID, 'A' AS Decode, COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
  FROM AnonymousTable
 WHERE "group" LIKE '%1%'
 GROUP BY GroupID, Decode
UNION
SELECT 2 AS GroupID, 'B' AS Decode, COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
  FROM AnonymousTable
 WHERE "group" LIKE '%1%'
 GROUP BY GroupID, Decode
UNION
SELECT 3 AS GroupID, 'C' AS Decode, COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
  FROM AnonymousTable
 WHERE "group" LIKE '%1%'
 GROUP BY GroupID, Decode
UNION
SELECT 4 AS GroupID, 'D' AS Decode, COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
  FROM AnonymousTable
 WHERE "group" LIKE '%1%'
 GROUP BY GroupID, Decode
UNION
SELECT 5 AS GroupID, 'E' AS Decode, COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
  FROM AnonymousTable
 WHERE "group" LIKE '%1%'
 GROUP BY GroupID, Decode
```

But this doesn't scale well; add another 5 groups and it is extremely unpleasant; add 500 and it is unmanageable.  You would do better to store the data in a properly normalized table which could then be analyzed using simpler SQL.

---

#### An alternative schema design and query

```
Users                     UserGroups          Groups
ID        Name            UserID GroupID      ID         Decode
1         Supreeth        1      1            1          A
2         Aishu           1      2            2          B
3         Arvi            2      1            3          C
4         Gani            2      2            4          D
5         Jyo             2      5            5          E
6         Savi            3      3
                          4      4
                          4      5
                          ...
```

Here is the simplified query, which will probably perform a lot better than the original, and which will scale to any number of groups (up into the millions if you want them):

```
SELECT u.GroupID, g.Decode, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM UserGroups AS u
  JOIN Groups     AS g ON u.GroupID = g.ID
 GROUP BY u.GroupID, g.Decode
```

Normalization makes life easier — that's one reason for doing it!

Comment: As `GROUP`is a reserved word it needs to be enclosed in brackets in the WHERE clause, but I'm sure you know this and just forgot :)
Also I can't run this without getting an error on the `GROUP BY`statement: Invalid column name GroupID and the same for Decode.

Comment: You're correct that GROUP is a reserved keyword.  I'll fix that.  The SQL standard way of dealing with that is using double quotes around the name to make it into a delimited identifier.  Microsoft SQL Server uses square brackets (so does Sybase, I believe).  MySQL uses back-ticks for the job.  Etc.  All SQL DBMS I know of do support double quotes.

Comment: Ah, I didn't look at the tag for the question and just assumed it was SQL Server, hence the bracket ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered but i wanted to share my point of view.

What i do is actually splitting the comma separated column into rows and then i just apply the count. As for the decode, instead of manually doing the job i just add the number to 64 and apply the CHAR function that will return the capital letter of the ASCII table...

```
SELECT Decode,
       COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
           CHAR(64+CONVERT(INT,String)) AS Decode,
           string
    FROM
    (
           SELECT A.[id],  
                Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
           FROM  
               (
               SELECT id,
                      CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING([GROUP],0,LEN([GROUP])), ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
               FROM  Table1
               ) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
     ) T1
  ) T2
 GROUP BY Decode
 ORDER BY Decode
```

Just to let you know i got here the [Column To Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873701/convert-comma-separated-column-value-to-rows).

I have also created a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b10b4/29)

I would have given my answer yesterday, but i was preoccupied...sorry

Giannis