# Split a delimited string twice into a two column table

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, split

I have an array with the following format:

- Values are surrounded by double quotation marks `""`
- Columns are separated by commas `,`
- Rows are separated by semi-colons `;`
- Array is surrounded by curly brackets `{}`

For example, the following string...

```
{"73","2022-09-02 11:42:37.00";"118","2022-08-31 10:41:59.00";"123","2022-09-01 15:26:06.00"}
```

...would represent a two-column table with the values 73, 118, and 123 in the first column and 2022-09-02 11:42:37.00, 2022-08-31 10:41:59.00, and 2022-09-01 15:26:06.00 in the second column.

I would like to convert this array to a table in SQL.

After looking at several other similar questions, I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function) that led me to this solution...

```
DECLARE @array varchar(max)

SET @array = '{"73","2022-09-02 11:42:37.00";"118","2022-08-31 10:41:59.00";"123","2022-09-01 15:26:06.00"}'

SET @array = REPLACE(REPLACE(@array, '{', ''), '}', '')

SELECT Min(CASE b.ordinal WHEN '1' THEN b.value END) 'ID',
       Min(CASE b.ordinal WHEN '2' THEN b.value END) 'Date'
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@array, ';', 1) a
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(a.value, ',', 1) b
GROUP BY a.ordinal
```

There is also this option...

```
DECLARE @array varchar(max)

SET @array = '{"73","2022-09-02 11:42:37.00";"118","2022-08-31 10:41:59.00";"123","2022-09-01 15:26:06.00"}'

SET @array = REPLACE(REPLACE(@array, '{', ''), '}', '')

SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(a.value, ',', '.'), 2) 'ID',
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(a.value, ',', '.'), 1) 'Date'
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@array, ';', 1) a
```

However, I'm fairly new to SQL Server, so I have some questions:

1. Which solution is preferable and why? Or is there a better option besides these two? I've seen [some people use XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015887/sql-splitting-a-twice-delimited-string-into-a-two-column-table) but I know very little about XML and wasn't sure if that'd work with this implementation since both columns have a variable number of characters.
2. Why does the PARSENAME function automatically remove the double quotes around the values?
3. Will both of these options keep the values paired correctly? (e.g., "73" is always in the same row as "2022-09-02 11:42:37.00"?)
4. Bonus Question: If this were to be a 3+ columned table, would one solution be better over another?

Comment: Questions on this site need to ask a single, specific, unopinionated question.

Comment: Don't use XML if you don't have to: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6390/sql-server-split-string-replacement-code-with-stringsplit/

Comment: `parsename()` is a hack in this usage. It's supposed to be about finding objects in the database and quotes aren't part of database names.

Comment: The order of results from `string_split()` is not guaranteed. You'd probably need to match on ordinal. See documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Be aware that if the quoted content includes any commas or semicolons, neither of the above techniques will produce the expected results. If the source data only contains numbers and date/time values (as in your sample data), you should be okay. If the quoted strings might contain arbitrary content, you would be better off parsing the data using a languages with better text processing tools, such as regexes. (Given the above two choices though, my preference from a readability point of view is the double string_split() approach.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach that uses `string_split()` and a bit of JSON

Note:  If you want a Pos3 (or more) ... Just follow the patterm.  If there is no value, it will return NULL.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '{"73","2022-09-02 11:42:37.00";"118","2022-08-31 10:41:59.00";"123","2022-09-01 15:26:06.00"}'

Select ID   = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
      ,Date = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
 From  string_split(replace(replace(@S,'{',''),'}',''),';') A
 Cross Apply (values ( ('['+A.Value+']') )) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
ID      Date
73      2022-09-02 11:42:37.00
118     2022-08-31 10:41:59.00
123     2022-09-01 15:26:06.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to split your string into a table is to convert the string to an array of arrays and then use OPENJSON.

```
/* Demo for linking another table */
DECLARE @tmpTable table(id int, someColumn nvarchar(50))
insert into @tmpTable
values (73, '73 Data')

/* Handle String */
DECLARE @array varchar(max) = '{"73","2022-09-02 11:42:37.00", "more data";
                               "118","2022-08-31 10:41:59.00";
                               "123","2022-09-01 15:26:06.00"}'
SET @array = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@array
                , '{', '[[')
                , ';', '],[')
                , '}', ']]')

/* Query */
 SELECT 
    d.ID,
    d."Date",
    d.col3,
    t.someColumn
 FROM OPENJSON(@array) 
 WITH (
    ID int '$[0]',
    "Date" datetime '$[1]',
    col3 nvarchar(50) '$[2]'
 ) d
LEFT JOIN @tmpTable t on t.id = d.ID
```

Use "WITH" to assign column names, type, and the position the value is at.

I added a table to demo joining. Also added a third col in the first row to show how to handle more columns.

**Results**

| ID | Date | col3 | someColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 73 | 2022-09-02 11:42:37.000 | more data | 73 Data |
| 118 | 2022-08-31 10:41:59.000 | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | 2022-09-01 15:26:06.000 | NULL | NULL |