# SELECT ...WHERE IN not finding values in a query-generated list

Tags: sql

I need to find cases where individuals have entered an invalid response in a questionnaire. The list of valid responses is saved as a semicolon-separated string in a table, like this: "starfish;bass;cod;dolphin;shark;"

If I run the query against the text value, it will tell me that "starfish" is not in the list, because I haven't separated the values:

```
SELECT 'starfish' as value, 'starfish;bass;cod;dolphin;shark;' as 'is not in this list' 
WHERE 'starfish' NOT IN ('starfish;bass;cod;dolphin;shark;')
```

I *could* go through a fairly manual process where I convert the semicolon list into a quote and comma list. When I do that, it works:

```
SELECT 'starfish' as value, 'starfish'',''bass'',''cod'',''dolphin'',''shark' as 'is not in this list' 
WHERE 'starfish' NOT IN  ('starfish','bass','cod','dolphin','shark')
```

Now, here's where my problem lies: 
I'd like to save some steps by having my query convert the semicolon string into an apostrophe/comma separated list. However, when I do that, SQL acts as if my value is not in the list.

```
SELECT 'starfish' as value, (''''+REPLACE(LEFT(RTRIM('starfish;bass;cod;dolphin;shark;'),LEN(RTRIM('starfish;bass;cod;dolphin;shark;'))-1),';',''',''')+'''') as 'is not in this list'
WHERE 'starfish' not in (''''+REPLACE(LEFT(RTRIM('starfish;bass;cod;dolphin;shark;'),LEN(RTRIM('starfish;bass;cod;dolphin;shark;'))-1),';',''',''')+'''')
```

It appears that SQL doesn't recognize my query-generated list of valid values as a list. Any way to fix?

Comment: I think your trouble is the quotes themselves. 'starfish' should be `starfish`, for instance.  (edit:  the single quotes disappear in a comment.  The character should be the one in the top-left of the keyboard.)

Comment: You are making it hard for yourself by storing the values as a string. Separate the answers in to rows and your search becomes a trivial `SELECT ... WHERE ...` or `EXISTS...` statement. There are loads of answers in SO for splitting a string in to rows, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873701/convert-comma-separated-column-value-to-rows

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use LIKE operator and wildcards.

```
select * from 
(
SELECT 'starfish' as value, 'starfish;bass;cod;dolphin;shark;' as notlist from dual
)
WHERE ';'|| notlist not like '%;'||value||';%';
```