# Make multiple rows from cell value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column named `Item(varchar(max))` in my SQL server it contains cell data as follow:

> '1|2|3|4|5'

I want output as :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is it possible to do so using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yes. Here is a good reference for a bunch of ways to split strings: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: The best solution would be to stop storing delimited values. It violates 1NF and is a serious pain to work with.

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13873801/2630032

Comment: For SQL Server **2016**, use `SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('1|2|3|4|5','|')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I **highly** advise separating yourself from delimited values, if you *have* to use them, you can use the following method:

**Create the Table Function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitStringByPipe
(@string nvarchar(500))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
 SELECT  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@string, '|', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)     
)
GO
```

**Execute the function:**

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitStringByPipe('1|a|5|z|r')
```

**Returns:**

```
  | String
1 | 1
2 | a
3 | 5
4 | z
5 | r
```

Comment: Sir, i want count of  '1' after receiving output as desired..Please Help

Comment: Please provide an example of the table you'll be selecting from, and your final desired output. Without knowing anything about your structure, I cannot elaborate on my answer any further.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR XML (SQL Server)**

> A SELECT query returns results as a rowset. You can optionally
>   retrieve formal results of a SQL query as XML by specifying the FOR
>   XML clause in the query.

[More Detail for XML(SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)

```
;WITH CTE1
AS
(
SELECT CAST(('<r><c>' + REPLACE(TestColumn, '|', '</c></r><r><c>') + '</c></r>' ) AS XML) XmlColumn
FROM tbl_Employee
),
TBL2
AS
(
SELECT  CAST(Col.query('./text()') AS VARCHAR(10))Result
FROM 
CTE1 CROSS APPLY 
XmlColumn.nodes('/r/c') As Tab(Col)
)
SELECT * FROM TBL2
```

**Output :**

```
 Result 
-  1 -
-  2 -
-  3 -
-  4 - 
-  5 -
```