# multi value in same record sql

Tags: sql, join, multivalue

I have 4 tables :

1. The main table `Applications` with sample data like this:

   ```
   Id | Craft_Name | Area     | PPE       | Potential
   ---+------------+----------+-----------+-------------
    1 | anas       | 1, 2, 3, | 4, 1, 3,  | 4, 2,
   ```
2. Second table `Area`:

   ```
   Id | Area
   ---+----------
    1 | Jordan
    2 | USA
    3 | China
   ```
3. third table `PPE`

   ```
   Id | PPE 
   ---+-----------------
    1 | Safety Shoes   
    2 | Safety Gloves  
    3 | Electrical Gloves
    4 | Thermal Gloves
   ```
4. Fourth table `Potential`:

   ```
   ID | Potential
   ---+----------------------
    1 | Working at Height
    2 | Falling Objects
    3 | Sharp Edges
    4 | Inhalation
   ```

Finally I need the result of SQL query as follows:

```
Id | Craft_Name | Area                | PPE                                                   | Potential
---+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------
 1 | anas       | Jordan, USA, China, | Thermal Gloves, Working at Height, Electrical Gloves, | Inhalation, Falling Objects,
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Revise your design and don't use such lists. That's just making things complicated. Use linking tables.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. PS [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/3404097)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Comma Separated column value to rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873701/convert-comma-separated-column-value-to-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in 2 ways.

1. to change your applications table structure to include new 3 many to many relation tables. (recommended and its easier to do any type on analysis)
2. or you can use the following code which is so complicated and combining many complex queries in it.

   ```
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AreaTable') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #AreaTable
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PPETable') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #PPETable

   ; WITH AreaTable AS (
       SELECT 
           A.ID, A.CreaftName, AreaName
       FROM  
           (
               SELECT T1.ID, T1.CreaftName,T1.[AreaIDs],T2.my_Splits
               FROM
                   (
                       SELECT *,
                           CAST('<X>'+replace([AreaIDs],',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as my_Xml 
                       FROM [dbo].[Applications]) T1
                       CROSS APPLY
                       (
                           SELECT 
                               my_Data.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as my_Splits
                           FROM 
                               T1.my_Xml.nodes('X') as my_Data(D)
                       ) T2
                   ) A 
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[Areas] B on A.my_splits = B.ID
   )

   --SELECT * FROM TempTable

   SELECT DISTINCT ST2.ID, St2.CreaftName,
       SUBSTRING(
           (
               SELECT ','+ ST1.AreaName  AS [text()]
               FROM AreaTable ST1
               WHERE ST1.ID = ST2.ID
               ORDER BY ST1.ID
               FOR XML PATH ('')
           ), 2, 1000) [Areas]
   INTO #AreaTable
   FROM [dbo].[Applications] ST2

   ;WITH PPETable AS (
       SELECT 
           A.ID, A.CreaftName, PPEName
       FROM  
           (
               SELECT T1.ID, T1.CreaftName,T1.PPEIDs,T2.my_Splits
               FROM
                   (
                       SELECT *,
                           CAST('<X>'+replace(PPEIDs,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as my_Xml 
                       FROM [dbo].[Applications]) T1
                       CROSS APPLY
                       (
                           SELECT 
                               my_Data.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as my_Splits
                           FROM 
                               T1.my_Xml.nodes('X') as my_Data(D)
                       ) T2
                   ) A 
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[PPE] B on A.my_splits = B.ID
   )

   --SELECT * FROM TempTable

   SELECT DISTINCT ST2.ID, St2.CreaftName,
       SUBSTRING(
           (
               SELECT ','+ ST1.PPEName  AS [text()]
               FROM PPETable ST1
               WHERE ST1.ID = ST2.ID
               ORDER BY ST1.ID
               FOR XML PATH ('')
           ), 2, 1000) [PPEs]
   INTO #PPETable
   FROM [dbo].[Applications] ST2

   SELECT MainTable.ID, MainTable.CreaftName, A.Areas, B.[PPEs]
   FROM 
       [dbo].[Applications] AS MainTable
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #AreaTable AS A ON MainTable.ID = A.ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #PPETable AS B ON MainTable.ID = B.ID


   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AreaTable') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #AreaTable
   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PPETable') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #PPETable
   ```

and you can use the following code to generate the tables i did create this script with for your reference

```
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PPE]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[PPE]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Areas]    Script Date: 23/12/2018 10:43:40 AM ******/
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Areas]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Areas]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Applications]    Script Date: 23/12/2018 10:43:40 AM ******/
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Applications]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Applications]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Applications]    Script Date: 23/12/2018 10:43:40 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Applications]') AND type in (N'U'))
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Applications](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [CreaftName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [AreaIDs] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [PPEIDs] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Applications] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    END
    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Areas]    Script Date: 23/12/2018 10:43:40 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Areas]') AND type in (N'U'))
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Areas](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [AreaName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Ares] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    END
    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PPE]    Script Date: 23/12/2018 10:43:40 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PPE]') AND type in (N'U'))
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PPE](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [PPEName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_PPE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    END
    GO
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Applications] ON 

    INSERT [dbo].[Applications] ([ID], [CreaftName], [AreaIDs], [PPEIDs]) VALUES (1, N'Anas', N'1,3,2,', N'1,3')
    INSERT [dbo].[Applications] ([ID], [CreaftName], [AreaIDs], [PPEIDs]) VALUES (2, N'Islam', N',6,5,3', N'2')
    INSERT [dbo].[Applications] ([ID], [CreaftName], [AreaIDs], [PPEIDs]) VALUES (3, N'Mohammad', N'4', NULL)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Applications] OFF
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Areas] ON 

    INSERT [dbo].[Areas] ([ID], [AreaName]) VALUES (1, N'Jordan')
    INSERT [dbo].[Areas] ([ID], [AreaName]) VALUES (2, N'China')
    INSERT [dbo].[Areas] ([ID], [AreaName]) VALUES (3, N'USA')
    INSERT [dbo].[Areas] ([ID], [AreaName]) VALUES (4, N'Colombia')
    INSERT [dbo].[Areas] ([ID], [AreaName]) VALUES (5, N'Costa Rica')
    INSERT [dbo].[Areas] ([ID], [AreaName]) VALUES (6, N'Panama')
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Areas] OFF
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PPE] ON 

    INSERT [dbo].[PPE] ([ID], [PPEName]) VALUES (1, N'Safety Shoes')
    INSERT [dbo].[PPE] ([ID], [PPEName]) VALUES (2, N'Safety Gloves')
    INSERT [dbo].[PPE] ([ID], [PPEName]) VALUES (3, N'Electrical Gloves')
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PPE] OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

For example - Area table (continue the other tables)

```
select 
    (select Area.Area + ',' 
     from dbo.Area 
     where charindex(',' + cast(Area.Id as varchar(10)) + ',', ',' + isnull(Applications.Area, '') + ',') > 0 
     for xml path('')) 
from 
    dbo.Applications
```

Comment: Right. continue that way to the other fields