# How can I get comma delimited values into new row in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, csv, google-bigquery

I have imported my BigQuery database into spreadsheet using the SyncWith add-on. Inside on of my columns I have a CSV I want to put those values into new rows.

> This is what I have

| model | alarm |
| --- | --- |
| X | 1,34,60,1000 |
| Y | 2,4,5,900,1000 |
| Z | 1 |

> This is what I need

| model | alarm |
| --- | --- |
| X | 1 |
| X | 34 |
| X | 60 |
| X | 1000 |
| Y | 2 |
| Y | 4 |
| Y | 5 |
| Y | 900 |
| Y | 1000 |
| Z | 1 |

I found the following example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873701/convert-comma-separated-column-value-to-rows), but unfortunately it doesn't work for me because "CROSS APPLY" is not recognized in BigQuery. Is there a BigQuery alternative to this code below.

```
 SELECT A.[id],  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT [id],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([string], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  TableA) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
with mytable as (
    select "X" as model, "1,34,60,1000" as alarm union all 
    select "Y", "2,4,5,900,1000" union all 
    select "Z", "1"
)
select model, newalarm
from mytable, unnest(split(alarm)) as newalarm
```

[image]